# Is is possible to iterate over the keys of a union type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to iterate over the keys of a union type in Typescript, similarly to how you can use `Object.keys(someVar).map()`, for example?

An example type could be:

```
type Status = "status_1" | "status_2" | "status_3"
```

An alternative I've seen is to make an immutable array and then use the `typeof` operator with indexing to mimic this functionality, but this seems clumsy

```
export const CaseStatuses = ["status_1", "status_2", "status_3"] as const;
export type CaseStatus = typeof CaseStatuses[number];
```

Comment: TypeScript's types **do not exist** at runtime, because they're erased in compilation and all you're left with is the JavaScript.

Comment: What does `const CaseStatuses = ["status_1" | "status_2" | "status_3"] as const;` even mean?  You are using the bitwise `|` operator on strings?  That's not how anything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the immutable array, you can use an enum type instead of a union type. It's the only type not erased at compilation time (Enums are transpiled to an object when compiled). Then, use `Object.keys()`/`Object.values()` to iterate over it.

```js
enum Status {
  status_1 = "status_1",
  status_2 = "status_2",
  status_3 = "status_3",
}

// Iterate over it
console.log(Object.values(Status))
```

Comment: Very nice. I'll take a look at them in the docs.

Comment: Note `const enum`s _do_ get erased.